# What does the audio symbol at your feet mean in nba 2k20

Tags: nba2k20

I get an audio symbol next to my foot when playing in the Rec Center? Are my teammates trying to talk to me? I don't have a headset.

Comment: Can you describe the 'audio symbol'? Is it a speaker? A musical note?

Answer (score 1):

volume symbol?
then, a headset is a must

also, check your privacy/audio settings.
Make sure your not in a party if your trying to hear them. Make sure its set to game chat, thats the only problems ive had with hearing audio